# Unable to store YouTube videos's subtitle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pytube

I wanted to store YouTube video's subtitle in Pandas's column. But the given code is not storing any data in the panda dataframe's cell.

```
 df
 video_link
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKpcwdYVpKA
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg0_oQYK5WY
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA99TKMctJY

df['subtitle_english']=''
for i, row in df.iterrows():
try:
   myVideo = YouTube(row['video_link'])
   caption = myVideo.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
   df.at[i,'subtitle_english']=caption.generate_srt_captions()
except:
   pass
```

The above code is not storing any subtitle, even it exists. Is there any way to store the subtitle?

Answer (score 1):

The provided videos don't have English subtitles. You will see that your code works (if you indent the try/except blocks) by using the language code `'a.pt'`, this will load the Portugese auto-generated subtitles of the third video. In any case iterating over each row is quite inefficient in Pandas, so you could wrap it in a function and apply the `video_link` column to the function. Again, you will only get results if the video actually contains English subtitles.

```
def get_subtitles(url):
    myVideo = YouTube(url)
    caption = myVideo.captions.get_by_language_code('en') # use 'a.en' for auto-generated subtitles
    return caption.generate_srt_captions() if caption else None

df['subtitle_english'] = df['video_link'].apply(get_subtitles)
```